# How to refresh (rebuild) tree in Nestable plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-nestable

I use [Nestable2](https://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable2) plugin to create tree in my project.

I need to refresh (rebuild) tree when it was updated by ajax. I used next code. It create tree correctly but I can't change (move) depth (level). How to fix this problem?

```
$('.dd').nestable('init').nestable({maxDepth: 6}).nestable('collapseAll');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
$('.dd').nestable('destroy');
$('.dd').nestable({maxDepth: 6}).nestable('collapseAll');
```

Comment: In my case, the + and - arrows are not appearing back after rebuilding this way.

Comment: @AmitShah After destroying the plugin, you have to reinitialize it using however you initialized Nestable at the start, i.e. `$('#nestable').nestable('init')`.

Answer (score -1):

**This code works for me:**

Change below in the `jquery.nestable.js` file:

**Find this:**

```
item = $.extend({}, li.data()),
```

**Replace with:**

```
item = $.extend({}, li[0].dataset),
```

Comment: This solution not affecting the result at all